# Running glmnet package in R, getting error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", maybe due to missing values?

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to use `glmnet` from the `glmnet` package to run a LASSO regression.

I am using the following command:

```
library(glmnet)
glmnet(a,b,family="binomial",alpha=1)
```

And am getting the error:

```
> Error in if (!all(o)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

`a` is a matrix, with numerical values.
`b` is a vector with a factor as values.

However, `b` has some missing values. I am suspecting this might be what is causing the error. However, I don't see an option to exclude `NA`s in the glmnet documentation.

Comment: Could you please add a `dput(a)` and `dput(b)` as well as the `traceback()` after you run your `glmnet` to help us replicate and diagnose?

Comment: you have NAs in the class you are trying to predict

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `glmnet` doesn't accept the full data frame with a formula (and thus no na.omit), but uses separate response and predictor matrices, you will have to find which values in `b` are missing, and then subset your predictor matrix to exclude those rows.

```
library(glmnet)

set.seed(123)
a <- matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
b <- as.factor(sample(0:1,100,replace = TRUE))

b[10] <- NA

na_index <- is.na(b)
res <- glmnet(a[!na_index, ], b[!na_index], family = "binomial", alpha = 1)
```